# Pandas dataframe: Copying field value from one dataframe to another based on matching list of fields

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: Small_dataframe (2000 rows) and big_dataframe (1 million+ rows)

```
Small_dataframe has the following fields.  The object_type field contains values of interest:
object_type, feature_1, feature_2, feature_3 .... feature_100.
```

I need to copy object_type in each row of  Small_dataframe  to big_dataframe if a subset of fields in Small_dataframe matches the same subset in big_dataframe which looks as follows.

```
big_dataframe has the same fields (but object_type field in big_dataframe is initially empty):
object_type, feature_1, feature_2, feature_3 .... feature_100
```

Example of operation:

looking at row 0 in small Small_dataframe, I find that in this particular row 0, 3 features columns are not None or empty and all other feature fields (columns) are None or empty.  I would then check in big_dataframe to see if there are rows where the same 3 features (columns)  equal to small_dataframe 3 features (columns) and all other feature fields are None or empty.   If so, then set big_dataframe['object_type'] = small_dataframe['object_type'].

looking at row 1 in small Small_dataframe, I find that in this particular row 1, 8 features columns are not None or empty and other feature fields (columns) are None or empty.  I would then check in big_dataframe to see if there are rows where the same 8 features equal to small_dataframe 8 features (columns) and all other feature fields (columns) are None or empty.   If so, then set big_dataframe['object_type'] = small_dataframe['object_type'].

```
.
. and so on
.
```

looking at row #300 in small Small_dataframe, I find that in this particular row 1, 17 features columns are not None or empty and other feature fields are None or empty.  I would then check in big_dataframe to see if there are rows where the same 17 features equal to small_dataframe 17 features and all other feature fields are None or empty.   If so, then set big_dataframe['object_type'] = small_dataframe['object_type'].

I am looking to do this while maximizing the use of built-in functions to avoid pandas iterrows on one or both frames. Please note that the number of columns matches, as described above, changes from one row to the next.   I would appreciate any feedback on a more efficient way to do this with minimal looping.

Comment: Could you present an example of your dataframes with expected result. Please take a look at how to create [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'object_type':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'f1':[None,None,None,2,3,4,5,2],'f2':[None,1,2,None,None,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'object_type':[None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None],'f1':[None,None,None,2,3,4,5,2],'f2':[None,0,2,None,None,3,4,5]})
#object_type is at the zeroth location
df1.iloc[:,1:] == df2.iloc[:,1:]
equality_test = df1.iloc[:,1:] == df2.iloc[:,1:]
df2 = df2.mask(equality_test.all(axis=1), other=df1)
print(df2)
```

Comment: Awesome .... This is exactly what I am looking for.   I am a bit confused about this line.   df1.iloc[:,1:] == df2.iloc[:,1:]  how did this ends up being a pair  of  True  False or (True, False) for example.   I would appreciate pointing me to a good reference where this is discussed.   The confusion is that I would have expected a True or False, as opposed to a pair   True  False.   But again, you saved my day.   Many Many Thanks

Comment: Never mind ... it is a pair because we got 2 fields .... duh .... Sorry about the confusion .... Many thanks again